# Filter SELECT output by string in Spaql

Tags: filter, sparql

I have a Sparql query like this :

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX hrdata:<http://www.hrdata.com/ontologies/hrdata.owl#>
SELECT  ?tableName2 ?fieldName ?primaryKey1 ?primaryKey2 ?tableName1
WHERE {     ?tableName1 hrdata:hasField hrdata:EFFDT.
            ?fieldName hrdata:relatedField hrdata:EFFDT. 
            ?tableName2 hrdata:hasField ?fieldName.
            ?primaryKey1 hrdata:isPrimaryKey ?tableName1.
            ?primaryKey2 hrdata:isPrimaryKey ?tableName2.
       }
```

It returns a long list of different tableNames to me, because they have same property with name 'EFFDT'.
I want to add another condition to where like this, to tell it I mean those 'EFFDT' that are related to a table which name is 'xyz':

```
Filter ( ?tableName1 = 'xyz')
```

I google it a lot, but unfortunately none of the solution like what you can in the following page could help me.

- [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/3530/sparql-query-filtering-by-string](https://web.archive.org/web/20160525051439/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/3530/sparql-query-filtering-by-string)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you give an example of your current output, please?

Comment: The answer is something like this without filter: xx,yy,zz,dd,ff
Some lines with different tableNames1
I want just see those one which have same tableName1

Comment: So all of your variables (`?tableName2 ?fieldName ?primaryKey1 ?primaryKey2 ?tableName1`) are of the type string. and the out put is xx,yy,zz,dd,ff1 xx,yy,zz,dd,ff2 xx,yy,zz,dd,ff3 ? I really do not get what your output is and what you want it to be. It would help a lot if you could give an example of what is now and what you expect it to be.

Comment: You need to show a sample of your actual data, and the current output (and expected output) of the query. Otherwise we can only guess at what your query should look like. **Edit your question** to add these necessary details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?tableName1` is in the subject position do it's a URI or blank node.

`Filter ( ?tableName1 = 'xyz')` tests for a string.

If you mean the URI contains the string `xyz` then:

`Filter ( contains(str(?tableName1),'xyz'))`

Comment: As per the comments - showing the output without the filter would help.